# Mouseover events in one object, and mouse out events on an object resulting of the first event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

The title is a little bit messy, so let me try to explain in the actual question:

Suppose I have the following HTML setup.

```
<div id="userMenu">
    <div id="userMenu-expanderLink">Mouseover here!</div>
    <div id="userMenu-collapserLink">You can close the menu by mouse out.</div>
    <div id="userMenu-expandedContent">Extra Content</div>
</div>
```

Now, userMenu and userMenu-expanderLink are shown by default. userMenu-expandedContent and userMenu-collapserLink are hidden by default.
What I am trying to do in jQuery is to `slideDown` the `userMenu-expandedContent`when a `mouseover` event occurs on `userMenu-expander`. All good there, this is my code:

```
$("#userMenu-expanderLink").mouseover(function() {
    $("#userMenu-expandedContent").stop().slideDown(200);
    $("#userMenu-expanderLink").hide();
    $("#userMenu-collapserLink").show();

    $("#userMenu").addClass("userMenu-expanded");
});
```

As you can see, I'm also hiding the expanderLink and showing the collapserLink; and also adding a class called userMenu-expanded to #userMenu. Until now, this code has no problems. Everything works well.

But now, I want that when the user has a `mouseOut` event on `#userMenu.userMenu-expanded`, effectively moving his mouse out of the `#userMenu` that is expanded, I want when that happens, the `expandedContent` is `slideUp`'d, the expander and collapser links swapped, and the class removed. I know how to do that, but handling the event seems to be a problem.

Putting `$("#userMenu.userMenu-expanded")...` directly alongside the code I have of course does not work, since a div with such id and such class is only generated if the menu has been expanded, and the div's class is removed once the menu is collapsed. I don't directly use a mouseover/mouseout event on one object because I want the collapsing to be triggered only when the user takes his mouse out of the menu, not the expander link.

So, here's my problem. How can I get such mouse out event? I have tried adding the event handler in the callback of .addClass, but no avail, it would basically permanently close that expanded menu (basically I can't ever expand it again until I reload the page).

How can this be done? I'm not very experienced with jQuery, so a detailed answer would be most appreciated. I'm more interested on how can this be done rather than just accomplishing it, I want to learn ^_^.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a correct way to do this. This is my final implementation.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
// UserMenu Expander, which is also a form of drop down
$("#userMenu-expander").mouseenter(function() {
    //alert("Usermenu expanding…");
    $("#userMenu-expandedContent").slideDown(200, function() {
        $("#userMenu").addClass("userMenu-expanded");
    });
    $("#userMenu-expanderLink").hide();
        $("#userMenu-collapserLink").show();
});

$("#userMenu.userMenu-expanded").live('mouseleave', function() {
    //alert("Usermenu de-expanding…");
    $("#userMenu-expandedContent").slideUp(200);
    $("#userMenu-expanderLink").show();
        $("#userMenu-collapserLink").hide();

    $("#userMenu").removeClass("userMenu-expanded");
});
});
```